# Vhost Ubuntu 14.04 & Codeigniter

Tags: php, apache2

Good afternoon Community;

I need help with this, i just configure Vhost for my first time in Ubuntu, im using Codeigniter, now when i go to my page (190.8.41.166) only show this errors:

> =')) { error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED); } else { error_reporting(E_ALL &
>   ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE); } break; default:
>   header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503); echo 'The
>   application environment is not set correctly.'; exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
>   } /* *---------------------------------------------------------------
>   * SYSTEM FOLDER NAME *--------------------------------------------------------------- * * This variable must contain the name of your "system" folder. * Include
>   the path if the folder is not in the same directory * as this file. */
>   $system_path = 'system'; /*
>   *--------------------------------------------------------------- * APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
>   *--------------------------------------------------------------- * * If you want this front controller to use a different "application" *
>   folder than the default one you can set its name here. The folder *
>   can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server. If * you do,
>   use a full server path. For more info please see the user guide: *
>   https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html * * NO
>   TRAILING SLASH! */ $application_folder = 'application'; /*
>   *--------------------------------------------------------------- * VIEW FOLDER NAME
>   *--------------------------------------------------------------- * * If you want to move the view folder out of the application * folder
>   set the path to the folder here. The folder can be renamed * and
>   relocated anywhere on your server. If blank, it will default * to the
>   standard location inside your application folder. If you * do move
>   this, use the full server path to this folder. * * NO TRAILING SLASH!
>   */ $view_folder = ''; /* * -------------------------------------------------------------------- * DEFAULT CONTROLLER *
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------- * * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file. * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a *
>   specific controller class/function here. For most applications, you *
>   WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those * special
>   instances where you might want to override the standard * routing in a
>   specific front controller that shares a common CI installation. * *
>   IMPORTANT: If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be *
>   callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE *
>   specific controller. Leave the function name blank if you need * to
>   call functions dynamically via the URI. * * Un-comment the $routing
>   array below to use this feature */ // The directory name, relative to
>   the "controllers" folder. Leave blank // if your controller is not in
>   a sub-folder within the "controllers" folder // $routing['directory']
>   = ''; // The controller class file name. Example: mycontroller // $routing['controller'] = ''; // The controller function you wish to be
>   called. // $routing['function'] = ''; /* *
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------- * CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES *
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------- * * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file. * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application
>   between * multiple front controller files, with each file containing
>   different * config values. * * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array
>   below to use this feature */ //
>   $assign_to_config['name_of_config_item'] = 'value of config item'; //
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------- // END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS. DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE //
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------- /* * --------------------------------------------------------------- *
>   Resolve the system path for increased reliability *
>   --------------------------------------------------------------- */ // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests if
>   (defined('STDIN')) { chdir(dirname(**FILE**)); } if (($_temp =
>   realpath($system_path)) !== FALSE) { $system_path = $_temp.'/'; } else
>   { // Ensure there's a trailing slash $system_path =
>   rtrim($system_path, '/').'/'; } // Is the system path correct? if ( !
>   is_dir($system_path)) { header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.',
>   TRUE, 503); echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set
>   correctly. Please open the following file and correct this:
>   '.pathinfo(**FILE**, PATHINFO_BASENAME); exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG } /*
>   * ------------------------------------------------------------------- * Now that we know the path, set the main path constants * ------------------------------------------------------------------- */ // The name of THIS file define('SELF', pathinfo(**FILE**,
>   PATHINFO_BASENAME)); // Path to the system folder define('BASEPATH',
>   str_replace('\', '/', $system_path)); // Path to the front controller
>   (this file) define('FCPATH', dirname(**FILE**).'/'); // Name of the
>   "system folder" define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'),
>   '/'), '/')); // The path to the "application" folder if
>   (is_dir($application_folder)) { if (($_temp =
>   realpath($application_folder)) !== FALSE) { $application_folder =
>   $_temp; } define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
>   } else { if ( !
>   is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) {
>   header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503); echo 'Your
>   application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please
>   open the following file and correct this: '.SELF; exit(3); //
>   EXIT_CONFIG } define('APPPATH',
>   BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); } // The path to
>   the "views" folder if ( ! is_dir($view_folder)) { if ( !
>   empty($view_folder) &&
>   is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) { $view_folder =
>   APPPATH.$view_folder; } elseif ( !
>   is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) { header('HTTP/1.1 503
>   Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503); echo 'Your view folder path does
>   not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and
>   correct this: '.SELF; exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG } else { $view_folder =
>   APPPATH.'views'; } } if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== FALSE)
>   { $view_folder = $_temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; } else { $view_folder =
>   rtrim($view_folder, '/\').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; } define('VIEWPATH',
>   $view_folder); /* *
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------- * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE *
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------- * * And away we go... */ require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

i didn't find anything in google, please help me.

Comment: you haven't installed php

Comment: yes, it is installed, i also restart the service 2 times :(

Comment: have a look at your php.ini and PHP version. check for your short_open_tag setting

Comment: ok, let me see .............

Comment: what you have pasted in is the code igniter php file that has not been parsed by php which would indicate that php is not running.

Comment: The problem was the php ;) thanks